# is there anyway to force durandal to recreate view/controls on view revisits(invoke view attched event) while caching enabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js, kendo-grid, durandal-2.0

I am using a kendo UI grid on a view, which is part of durandal 2.0 app using knockout for mvvm. 
On a specific view, there is need to display a kendo grid having dynamic number of columns,
so every time view is visited, grid columns may have different count than the last visits.
Now as caching is enabled(applicable to this view too), so for subsequent visits grid rows are changing to reflect data change, but grid header(including number of columns) remains as it was during very first visit to view.

Note: if i disable caching for compose which is used to compose this view, grid loads fine with varying number of columns every time, but can't disable caching just because one control is not loading fine, and due to business needs.

so i wanted to know is there any way i can tell durandal to run viewattached event every time a specific view is visited, if not possible then is it possible that i can ask Durandal to recreate kendo grid control on every visit(so it doesn't uses what it created and having in cache of view)... i also tried always run viewattached on comose, but that brings a flicker when visiting the view hence i feel kind of disables caching for compose(but i can't do that a this compose is common for more than a view, which all should use caching)

Answer (score 0):

Your viewmodel should return a constructor function instead of an object literal.  But without seeing your code, it is difficult to identify your specific problem.